# How do I group the data in the following format?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

Using the following table

```
OrderDate     OrderID
[dates]       [id]
```

I want to display in the following format :

```
quater name   nooforders
q1            10
q2            10
q3            20
```

I have tried the following query :

`select count(order_id)no_of_orders,
(case when month(order_date)<=4 then 'q1' when month(order_date)<=8 then 'q2' when month(order_date)<=12 then 'q3' end)quarter
from bab_orders
group by quarter;`

However this query does not show the value of a particular quarter when it has no orders associated with it. How do I display that?

Answer (score 1):

To display the given format, you can use the following queries instead:

> For MySQL, use the following:

```
  SELECT QuaterName, COUNT(OrderID) FROM
    (
        SELECT QUARTER(OrderDate) QuaterName, OrderID from bab_orders
    ) T1 group by QuaterName;
```

> for Oracle use the following:

```
SELECT QuaterName, COUNT(OrderID) FROM
(
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OrderDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Q') 
              QuaterName, OrderID from bab_orders
) T1 group by QuaterName;
```

> to show always the Quarters even if you don't have a data, execute the
>   following query:

```
SELECT QRTR, COUNT(OrderID) TheCount FROM
(
  SELECT QUARTER('2014-01-01')  QRTR  
  union
  SELECT QUARTER('2014-04-01')  QRTR
  union
  SELECT QUARTER('2014-08-01')  QRTR
  union
  SELECT QUARTER('2014-12-01')  QRTR
)  QRTR_T
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT QUARTER(OrderDate) Quater, OrderID from bab_orders
) ORDERS
on Quater = QRTR
group by QRTR
```

Comment: The query does not return a particular quarter when there are no orders in that quarter. I want to display that quarter as well with count as 0

Comment: I updated the copy above, Check the updated third query

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a query that generates the first day of every quarter and left join it to a summary.

## QUARTER NAME QUERY

For this example, let's start from 2011. Here is that query

```
SELECT qtr,CONCAT(YEAR(qtr),'Q',QUARTER(qtr)) qtrname FROM
(SELECT MAKEDATE(YYYY,1) + INTERVAL (qtrnum - 1) QUARTER qtr FROM
(SELECT 1 qtrnum UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) Q INNER JOIN
(SELECT 2011 YYYY UNION SELECT 2012 UNION SELECT 2013 UNION SELECT 2014) Y) AA;
```

Here is the output of that query

```
mysql> SELECT qtr,CONCAT(YEAR(qtr),'Q',QUARTER(qtr)) qtrname FROM
    -> (SELECT MAKEDATE(YYYY,1) + INTERVAL (qtrnum - 1) QUARTER qtr FROM
    -> (SELECT 1 qtrnum UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) Q INNER JOIN
    -> (SELECT 2011 YYYY UNION SELECT 2012 UNION SELECT 2013 UNION SELECT 2014) Y) AA;
+------------+---------+
| qtr        | qtrname |
+------------+---------+
| 2011-01-01 | 2011Q1  |
| 2011-04-01 | 2011Q2  |
| 2011-07-01 | 2011Q3  |
| 2011-10-01 | 2011Q4  |
| 2012-01-01 | 2012Q1  |
| 2012-04-01 | 2012Q2  |
| 2012-07-01 | 2012Q3  |
| 2012-10-01 | 2012Q4  |
| 2013-01-01 | 2013Q1  |
| 2013-04-01 | 2013Q2  |
| 2013-07-01 | 2013Q3  |
| 2013-10-01 | 2013Q4  |
| 2014-01-01 | 2014Q1  |
| 2014-04-01 | 2014Q2  |
| 2014-07-01 | 2014Q3  |
| 2014-10-01 | 2014Q4  |
+------------+---------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## SUMMARY QUERY

Your group by query needs to be grouped by the first day of OrderDate's quarter

```
SELECT qtr,COUNT(1) RowCount FROM
(SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(OrderDate,1))+INTERVAL (QUARTER(OrderDate) - 1) QUARTER qtr
FROM bab_orders WHERE (whatever date range)) QtrSum GROUP BY qtr;
```

## COMBINE TO FORM LEFT JOIN

Now, you left join the Quarter Name Query to the Summary

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(YEAR(AAA.qtr),'Q',QUARTER(AAA.qtr)) QuarterName,
    IFNULL(RowCount,0) NumberOfOrders
FROM
(
    SELECT MAKEDATE(YYYY,1) + INTERVAL (qtrnum - 1) QUARTER qtr FROM
    (SELECT 1 qtrnum UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) Q INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 2011 YYYY UNION SELECT 2012 UNION SELECT 2013 UNION SELECT 2014) Y
) AAA
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT qtr,COUNT(1) RowCount FROM
    (SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(OrderDate,1))+INTERVAL (QUARTER(OrderDate) - 1) QUARTER qtr
    FROM bab_orders WHERE (whatever date range)) QtrSum GROUP BY qtr
) BBB
USING (qtr);
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!